# Yii Cactive forms

Tags: php, forms, yii, yii-cactiverecord

Hi I want to create a contact form in YII view. i am using `CACtive` forms but the problem is it requires a model, I don't have a model, I am just calling a view without any model.
below is my code

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'fundraising-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'hideErrorMessage'=>true,
    ),
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
         'focus'=>array($model,'name'),
            )); 
  echo $form->labelEx('name_of_organization');
```

gives me the error
**Missing argument 2 for CActiveForm::labelEx(),**

Comment: As far as I know, You must use `AR` model while interacting with `CActiveForm`, Don't you have a model?

Comment: What is the reason not to use a model?

Comment: I dont need model here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I guess correctly, you don't have any table to store your data and you do not need any interaction between your model and database, and you just want to use `ActiveForm` features without a model. It's **impossible**. But there is a trick to solve this problem. You can easily create a fake model and use it into your `ActiveForm`.

First, Create a model in your models directory, **BUT NOT AN ORDINARY MODEL**. Like below:

```
class FakeModel extends CFormModel{
public $organizationName; //for example!
public $fullname; // for example!!
public $email; // for example!!!
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('email','email'),
        array('fullname,organizationName','required')
    );
}

public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'email'=>'E-Mail Address',
        'organizationName'=>'Organization Name',
        'fullname'=>'Full Name',
    );
}
}
```

Note that, `FakeModel` extended the `CFormModel` class.

Umm, Now you have a model just like other `AR`'s models :) You can send this model into your ActiveForm, even perform validation in your model.

```
$fakeModel=new FakeModel();
//for validation
if($fakeModel->validate()){
 // SEND EMAIL FOR EXAMPLE
}
```

As you can see, there is no interaction between your `ActiveForm` and **database**. Easily pass your `$fakeModel` as the `model`(second parameter) in your `CActiveForm`.

**UPDATE**
As you probably know, the real name is 'CFormModel'.

I hope it help :)

Comment: did the same way, created a fake model :)

Comment: Of course, this is not really a fake model, but what Yii calls a form model.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy definitly you are right. But I just mentioned it as a fake model with this manner that , it does not interact with db. Thanks for your attention

Comment: I just want to make sure that we don't start giving people the false impression that the only function of the model is to interact with the database. The model is the part of the application that models the business, or the problem that the application is meant to solve. It handles a lot more than persistence, and depending on the application and the manner of persistence, there may be no database interaction in a real model. Other things in a model? Validation rules, business rules, algorithms....